# how to open tcp port in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, port, tcp

I have a ubuntu server

How can i open a port ?

I have flushed the **iptables** and off'ed **ufw**

Provide me steps how to open a tcp port

Comment: Is there a service already listening in that port?

Comment: Please provide (as an edit to your question) the output of `iptables -L INPUT -v -n` and the port you want opening

Answer (score 0):

Your question is overly vague and probably insufficient to help you do what you're actually trying to do, but if you just want to open a port you can do it like so:

nc -l -p PORT_NUMBER

You can then pass data received on that port to a script by doing:

nc -l -p PORT_NUMBER | SCRIPT